# Does protrusion in pdfLaTeX or XeLaTeX work as it should?

Tags: microtype, protrusion

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true,final]{microtype}
\begin{document}
\section*{The Microtypesetting}
\noindent
A run of the mill paragraph with some text that goes blah blah blah etc.
\noindent
\textquoteleft
Wow! What a beauty!\textquoteright 
\end{document}
```

but `\textquoteleft` does not protrude well enough outside the box as en visaged here. I use TeX Live 2013 so it is not very old...should I try TeX Live 2014?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With TeX Live 2014 protrusion is working:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true,final]{microtype}
\begin{document}
\section*{The Microtypesetting}
\newcommand*{\test}{%
  \noindent
  A run of the mill paragraph with some text.
  \par\hrule height .5ex
  \vskip.5ex
  \noindent
  \textquoteleft
  Wow (lpcode = \the\lpcode\font`\`)! What a beauty!\textquoteright
  \par
}
\test

\lpcode\font`\`=1000
\test

\lpcode\font`\`=0
\test

\lpcode\font`\`=-1000
\test
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: I notice that `quote` doesn't fully extend out, there is a little bit of lag there. The `single-quote` left-alignment bangs into the leg of `A`. Thanks for showing that you can do an `lpcode` tweaking but is not the default wrong?

Comment: @Sukii It is dangerous to use high values for protrusion. The result can easily look worse than without protrusion. Of course, the values can be "optimized" for each character of each font to find a better comprimise, but I recommend spending time for it only, if there is nothing more important (the actual text, for example) to optimize and enough free/spare time.